# ASP .NET Web installator, url to website

Tags: asp.net, .net, visual-studio, url, installation

At beginning, I want thank you for all answers.

I have issue, how I can get URL installed web site after install, I need this to another project and I can't  find good way to get this url. I thought, about message to web site after install or option with checkbox for example "Open website" at end stage.

Where I should look for this, in IIS configuration or custom actions in installer project. All tips are welcome.

Once again thank, for all answers.

Comment: Sorry, your question isn't clear!

Comment: Why? Which part do you talking about? Anyway thank you for your answer.